# PHPDoc - how show the options

Tags: php, function, phpdoc

Imagine a function like this

```
function mytrim($str,$where)
{
     if ($where=="left")  return ltrim($str)
     if ($where=="right") return rtrim($str)

}
```

Its very important to me show what is the options of the where in this functions (right or left)

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to do it is

```
/**
 * @param string $str
 * @param left|right $where
 * @return mixed|string
 */
```

> will show "where: \left|\right"

There is a better way to do it ?

Comment: `* @param string $where Must be a value "left" or "right" `

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside that I don't think you should have this function in the first place, you could make use of [type hints and return types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php) to document the arguments instead of using PHPDoc:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

function mytrim(string $str, string $where): ?string
{
    if ($where=="left")  return ltrim($str);
    if ($where=="right") return rtrim($str);
}
```

Docs tend to get outdated fast while function signatures are always current.

Now you could argue that this will not tell you what you can provide for `$where` and you'd still need the PHPDoc to know how to `ltrim` and `rtrim`. You could utilize constants for that though, e.g.

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

const MYTRIM_LEFT = 'left';
const MYTRIM_RIGHT = 'right';

function mytrim(string $str, string $where): ?string
{
    if ($where === MYTRIM_LEFT)  return ltrim($str);
    if ($where === MYTRIM_RIGHT) return rtrim($str);
}
```

You'd still need to know that these constants exist though. That's why I'd probably convert your `mytrim` to a Strings class and define the constants declarations in there by. And/Or you add a check into the function that throws an error if the `$where` isn't "left" or "right".

[As of PHP 8.1 you could use enums](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.enumerations.php) to make it even more clear:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

enum MyTrim {
    case Left;
    case Right;
}

function mytrim(string $str, MyTrim $where): ?string
{
    if ($where === MyTrim::Left)  return ltrim($str);
    if ($where === MyTrim::Right) return rtrim($str);
}

echo mytrim(" test", MyTrim::Left); // prints "test"
```

Everything there is to know about how to use the code is now directly visible in the signature.

But coming back to my initial remark: you should not have this function in the first place. Since you need to specify whether it's a left or right trim, you don't win anything over directly using `ltrim` and `rtrim` in your code.